# in django how do I create a queryset to find double barrel names?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

In django, I have a table of people, each of which has a namefirst and namelast.

I want to do the sql:

```
select * from names where left(namefirst,1)=left(namelast,1).
```

Right now my best effort is

```
qs=People.objects.extra(select={'db':'select left(namefirst,1)=left(namelast,1)'})
```

but then if i stick a .filter(db=1) on that it generates an error.

I suppose I could order by db and just cut it off, but I know there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `extra` parameter doesn't look right.  You should be using the `where` parameter (not `select`):

```
People.objects.extra(where=['left(namefirst,1)=left(namelast,1)'])
```

Comment: yeah, i was trying to select the thing and then filter on it.  I should have just filtered on it directly.  thanks!